# Use an appropriate statistical test to test the manufacturer’s claim at significance level $α=0.05$.

Tags: statistics

> The manufacturer of the resistors claims that the expected maximum power at which the resistor fails is $0.25$. 
>  
>   You suspect this threshold is lower and therefore decide to measure the current and resistance at which the resistor breaks down. 
>  
>   By an ingenious application of Ohm’s Law this results in a sample mean of $\overline{x}_{20} = 0.21$ and a sample variance of $s^2_{20} = 0.01$ for the power. 
>  
>   You may assume that the measurements for the power are also normally distributed. 
>  
>   Use an appropriate statistical test to test the manufacturer’s claim at significance level $α=0.05$.

I assume that $H_0$: $\mu=0.25$ $H_1$: $\mu<0.25$

$P(T\geq0.21|H_0)\leq\alpha$

$Z=\frac{0.21-0.25}{\frac{\sqrt{0.01}}{\sqrt{20}}}=-1.788$

$P(Z\leq-1.788)=P(Z\geq1.788)= 0.0368$ (from the N(0,1) table)

I think that what I did is correct but I didn't use the value of $0.05$ for the significance level, how can I use it in this question? What I assumed is correct? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Compare the estimated probability ($0.0368$) with the criterion probability ($0.05$).

Comment: Or you compare the estimated probability with the criteria , as David mentioned above, or you could go to the table, obtain the Z-value for a probability of 0,05 and compare it with your Z .

Comment: But this isn't a Z-test...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a t test (not a z test) because the population standard deviation $\sigma$ is unknown and estimated by the sample standard deviation $S = 0.1 = \sqrt{.01}.$

Your statement of null and alternative hypotheses is OK.

Here is output from Minitab statistical software for the t test:

```
One-Sample T 

Test of μ = 0.25 vs < 0.25


 N    Mean   StDev  SE Mean  95% Upper Bound      T      P
20  0.2100  0.1000   0.0224           0.2487  -1.79  0.045
```

What you call the $Z$-statistic is actually the $T$-statistic.

The P-value is the probability under Student's t distribution with degrees of freedom $\nu = n - 1 = 20-1 = 19$ to the left of $T = -1.79.$ It is difficult to
find this P-value from printed tables of the t-distribution.

From a printed table you can find that the critical value for a left-sided test at the 5% level is -1.729.
Because $T = -1.79 < -1.729,$ you know that you can reject at the 5% level.

From R statistical software, as below
(also from Minitab and others), one can find the P-value
which agrees with the value in the printout: 0.045.

```
qt(.05, 19)
[1] -1.729133
pt(-1.79, 19)
[1] 0.04470223
```

---

*Note:* Student's t distribution with $\nu = 19$ is "close" to
a standard normal distribution, but not exactly. *If this were a z-test,* then the critical value would be
-1.645 and the P-value would be 0.367, as you say.

```
qnorm(.05)
[1] -1.644854
pnorm(-1.79)
[1] 0.03672696
```

It may be inevitable that every beginning statistics student must confuse a t-test with a z-test once during the first course. Perhaps this can be your *one* such mistake,
avoiding another on your next exam.

Below are plots of the density of $\mathsf{T}(19)$ (solid blue) and the density of $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1)$ (dotted). The vertical red line is at
$T = -1.79.$ The P-value of the t test is the area under the blue curve to the left of this red line. The correct 5% critical value for the t distribution is shown by the solid blue line.

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer and for your time BruceET, you are right I didn't recognize that it was a t-test, but now it's clear the reason, thanks again!